# Why is a placeholder return type not allowed for coroutines?

Tags: c++, placeholder, c++20, c++-coroutine

According to [C++20's coroutines specification](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/n4775.pdf):

> A function declared with a return type that uses a 
>   placeholder type shall not be a coroutine.

**Why is a placeholder type not allowed in such a case?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The coroutine machinery that gets used for a particular coroutine is based primarily on the function's return type. The return type is a coroutine future, from which the coroutine logic will deduce the coroutine promise object that will be used to transfer the actual value(s) generated by the coroutine to the caller through the returned future.

This means that of `co_await`, `co_yield`, and `co_return`, *none of them* actually use the return type of the coroutine (which, btw, is why `co_return` is spelled differently from `return`; it has a different meaning and behavior, so it gets a different keyword). `co_return` and `co_yield` are not given the future type itself; they're given a type which the promise/future can marshal to the user.

And the `co_await` expression's type has almost no relation to the promise/future of the coroutine. It's simply a value through which the coroutine can schedule its resumption and from which a value of some arbitrary type can be extracted. The scheduled resumption doesn't really care all that much about the particular future/promise of the current coroutine. You can `co_await` on a `std::future<T>`, even if your coroutine's future/promise type isn't `std::future` of any kind.

So there's no way to deduce what the coroutine's future/promise should be from the expression supplied to any of these keywords. Therefore, you must explicitly specify it.

Comment: It would still be nice to be able to do some deduction. For instance, imagine you could deduce `T` for return type `asio::awaitable<T>` from the common type of the expressions in `co_return` and `co_yield`. I would like to return a `unique_ptr` with a lambda custom deleter from a coroutine without using type erasure or having to declare a functor structure by hand.

Comment: @DeltA: "*from the common type of the expressions in co_return and co_yield.*" For many such types, `co_return` returns `void`; there is no "common type" between `void` and anything else. And even if they did, it would most certainly not be an instantiation of `asio::awaitable`. "*having to declare a functor structure by hand.*" What is it with some people and this need they have to not simply give a name to things? Why can't you just call the functor what it is? The amount of code won't even be all *that* much different.

Comment: I don't see how it would be valid to return `void` and something else in the same coroutine (I may be wrong). Also, I didn't mean to say that the compiler should deduce the return type to be an instantiation of `asio::awaitable`. I meant that given the hint that the return type was of the form `asio::awaitable<X>` it would be nice for it to be able to deduce `X`.

Comment: @DeltA: "*I don't see how it would be valid to return void and something else in the same coroutine*" For a coroutine, "returning", "yielding" and "awaiting" are three separate operations. It is perfectly reasonable for a coroutine to return nothing while yielding values.